# Formatting cell in quip doc through api

Tags: quip

I'm trying to use the Quip API to change values in a spreadsheet that has cells formatted with colors and I can't figure out how or if it is possible to match the new content with the existing formatting.

Using the `{{baseUrl}}/1/threads/edit-document` with a location of 4 (`replace_section`) and section ID of an individual cell, it seems the call strips out the `style` attribute from both the `< td>` and `< span>` tags that's put in when a user manually edits the document that I see when I do a `/threads/threadID` and just puts in the raw text.

I've tried passing in `< span style='background-color:blue'>new content< /span>` for example in the content field and the API seems to strip out the `span` (or `div`, or `p`, or `a`, or any other tag but `br` it seems) using the `html` format argument.

Is what I'm trying to do possible, and if so how?

It seems like a pretty simple function that I would think is possible somehow.

Also, a reference of what html tags are recognized under location 4, format html would be nice too since it seems to be limited (for example, can't put in a link with `< a href='..'>blah< /a>`)

Comment: +1 I am not able to get styles working in a spreadsheet cell (both in a spreadsheet and document). Though `style='background-color:blue'` works in documents to highlight spans.